# How do I determine the appropriate type for method parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

In Haskell, the language I'm most familiar with, there is a fairly precise way to determine the type of a variable.  However, in the process of learning C#, I've become somewhat confused in this regard.  For example, the signature for the `Array.Sort` method is:

```
public static void Sort(
    Array array
)
```

Yet, this method will raise an exception if the argument is `null`, multidimensional, or does not implement the `IComparable` interface.  So, why isn't the type `IComparable[]`, if possible?

Comment: Because it's a poorly defined method (by today's standards), and also because many of the tools one would use to apply some of those restrictions didn't exist in .NET 1.0, when the method was written.

Comment: Your title is a bit too general. Do you want an answer for that question? Then it is a subjective question that is opinion based. If you want only an answer on the specific question about `Array.Sort`  the title doesn't fit.

Comment: If you look at the actual implementation.. it is possible that a call to `TrySZSort` on `Array` is called. This is an internal CLR call that is probably expecting an `Array`.. not something that implements `IComparable`.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead `IComparable[]` (i.e. **not** `IComparable`) is an `Array`.

Comment: Uggghhhhh. I'm a bit basic at this hour of the morning. Thanks @millimoose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If one were to write the method today you'd use something like this:

```
public static void Sort<T>(T[] array)
    where T : IComparable // or even IComparable<T>
{ ... }
```

This can't enforce that the array isn't null at compile time (sadly) but it can ensure that the array is of a type that is comparable and that it is single dimensional.  The null check would still need to be a runtime check.

But this relies on generics, which weren't added to the language until .NET 2.0.  (This also uses method level generics, rather than class level generics, which weren't added until .NET 3.5)  `Array.Sort` was added to the language in .NET 1.0.  It hasn't been changed because that would be a breaking change, one that the language designers choose not to make.

Comment: Excellent, that looks much more familiar, and reasonable.

Comment: Such overload actually almost exists, there is [`public static void Sort<T>(T[] array)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4) (without the `IComparable` constraint), that was added in .Net 2.0.

Comment: @svick Of course, when there's a less restrictive overload of the same method it still means you don't get compile time errors when you pass in an invalid array.  The only advantage of having that as an additional overload is that that method can avoid boxing, unlike `Array`.  If it had a different name then you could ensure that you got a compiler error for passing in an invalid array instead of a runtime error.